# Some users experiencing NSInternalInconsistencyException crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, crash

Some users are experiencing a crash according to crashlytics. This is what the crash says.

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException attempt to insert
>   row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the
>   update

This is the code I am using.

```
- (void)insertArray:(NSNotification *)notification {
       [self.tableView beginUpdates];
       [self.arrayList insertObject:person atIndex:0];
       [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
       [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.arrayList count];
}
```

My table view data source and delegate are set and I personally never experience a crash. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Update your question with your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated it. Is it possible that the notification might be called before delegate and data source is set? I set up notification in viewdidload. Datasource and delegate are set through IB.

Comment: Is it possible that your `insertArray:` method can be called at a time that `self.arrayList` is `nil`? That would cause the error you see.

Comment: Actually, that seems possible. It is nil for a small time frame.

Comment: That's the issue. Calling `insertObjects` on `nil` still leaves you with `nil`. And calling `count` on `nil` gives you `0`. Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. I will accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that the number of rows returned by your data source's `numberOfRowsInSection` does does not account for the new row (you're still reporting that the table should have 0 rows even after inserting one). Your data source should be updated before performing any cell transactions.

Since you aren't experiencing it yourself, it seems that there must be a certain circumstance or edge case that prevents your data source from updating properly. Editing your question and showing your data source methods may provide some insight.